# jQuery / CSS - Target li a instead of li?

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I'm currently integrating bootstraps scrollspy on my website - and I'm also working with a menu like this: http://development.tobypitman.com/css/menu.html

Right now - I can target my li in the navigation - But what i want is to target the li a.

```
    selector = this.selector
      + '[data-target="' + target + '"],'
      + this.selector + '[href="' + target + '"]'

    active = $(selector)
      .parent('li')
      .addClass('active')
```

Anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alternatively use:

```
active = $(selector)
    .parent('li')
    .children('a')
    .addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this will work?

```
active = $(selector)
      .parent('li')
      .find('a')
      .addClass('active')
```

Comment: I just tried it - it does seem to work. When updated i checked with firebug and the active class was only set on the first 'li' not on the 'li a'. And it wasn't changing.

Comment: That's because it is only being applied to the parent li element of the selector, as coded.

Comment: Then how can i get it to target the li a ?

Comment: Well, you're not asking a clear question. Why don't you ask a specific question, and not `how can I get it to target the li a?` which obviously has multiple meanings. Keep in mind, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish - only you do.

Comment: Im sorry - i want to my navigation which consists of a unordered list with some <a> tags in it to be styled specially when the user is at a certain point of the website - there for i want to apply a class to the li a and not only the li - I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.MenuLList').find('a.Testing').hover(function () { $(this).addClass('Active'); }, function () { $(this).removeClass('Active'); });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .MenuLList
        {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .MenuLList li
        {
            margin: 5px 0px;
        }

        .MenuLList li a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .Inactive
        {
            color: Red;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: Yellow;
        }

        .Active
        {
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: Green;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: Lime;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="MenuLList">
        <li><a class="Inactive" href="#">Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="Testing Inactive" href="#">Test 2</a> </li>
        <li><a class="Testing Inactive" href="#">Test 3</a> </li>
        <li><a class="Testing Inactive" href="#">Test 4</a> </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <li><a class="Inactive" href="#">Test 1</a></li> does not have Testing css class. so that hover effect will not occur.